# How to collapse MS Access Table rows by matching IDs

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a table similar to the Example Source Table shown below that I would like to collapse based on the ID field (see Example Collapsed Table).  I can do this with code but it inflates my Access database beyound the 2 GB maximum size so I'm hoping there is a way to do it with a query.  I should probably note that for any given ID value I don't need to worry about more than one record having a value in field One, Two, Three, or Four.

Example Source Table:

```
ID  One Two  Three  Four
1   My       Is
1                   Matt
1       Name
2   My       Is     Matt
2       Name
3   My  Name Is     Matt
```

Example Collapsed Table:

```
ID  One Two   Three  Four
1   My  Name    Is   Matt
2   My  Name    Is   Matt
3   My  Name    Is   Matt
```

Comment: How can code inflate it to 2GB? How many records are we talking about?

Comment: You should have a "split" database as good practice, data tables in one, and essentially code in the other. I'm as surprised as DJ about code pushing it over 2GB but this would prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregate query which groups by ID and returns the `Max()` for each of those other 4 columns within each ID grouping.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Max(One),
    Max(Two),
    Max(Three),
    Max(Four)
FROM tblSource
GROUP BY ID;
```

If you want to store the results in a new table, convert the query to a "make table query".  If you already have your destination table created and want to add those results to it, convert the query to an "append query".

If you're approaching the 2 GB db file size limit, first use Compact & Repair to discard unused space.  If compact doesn't give you enough working room, create another db file and store the new (collapsed) table there.  You can link to it from your original database.

Comment: @Matt Crisler: Glad you found what you were looking for. Please mark the question as answered - this gives credit to HansUp and removes the question from the "not answered" list